# VBA Excel - VBA code to search cells for 1st 3 digits string and replace

Tags: vba, excel

I have a system generated excel sheet which has phone number of staff. What I wanted to do is to cleanup the numbers on the first column so it will show only the last 10digits(i.e 9151234567).

Ex. Some numbers show 00639151234567, +639151234567, 639151234567

Comment: RIGHT(string,number)

Answer (score 0):

```
phone_number = Right(phone_number, 10)
```